# No acl on nfs mount in linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, access-control-list

I have several RHEL6 machines. One is exporting an nfs mount to the rest. I have ACL's set on the server (set using `setfacl -m`), but none of the clients are seeing any of them.

Here is my export on server1:

```
/myexport    server2.example.com(rw,async,no_root_squash)
```

Here is my fstab on server2:

```
server1.example.com:/myexport  /mnt  nfs4  noatime,async,lock 0 0
```

I have tried adding acl to my fstab mount options with no luck. Anyone know why I cannot see the ACL's on the client?

Comment: what command do you use to get acls on the client?

Comment: I use getfacl, of course regardless of the commands I use, permission is denied to users who should have access.

Comment: for nfs, you have to use nfs4_getfacl/nfs4_setfacl from nfs4-acl-tools package

Comment: OK, so when I use nfs4_getfacl I see the proper acl on the directories BUT the system gives permission denied no matter what so why are the acl's not being obeyed?

Answer (score 7):

The ACL are used and active over NFS. Use the command `nfs4_getfacl` to show the ACL on an NFSv4 mount:

```
$ nfs4_getfacl /tmp/test

A::OWNER@:rwatTnNcCy
A::alice@nfsdomain.org:rxtncy
A::bob@nfsdomain.org:rwadtTnNcCy
A:g:GROUP@:rtncy
D:g:GROUP@:waxTC
A::EVERYONE@:rtncy
D::EVERYONE@:waxTC
```

The reason why the ACL look so different compared to Linux ACL? Because [NFSv4 ACL](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl) and *Linux ACL* acl(5) are completely different standard ! The Linux NFS server will translate the ACL back and forth.

It's very unfortunate that linux `ls` don't show `+` for file with NFSv ACL on the client.. that's misleading.

Comment: FYI:  On ubuntu, it may be necessary to install the "nfs4-acl-tools" package to see the the "nfs4_getfacl" and "nfs4_setfacl" commands.

Comment: Here's a link to a very good page that discusses ACLs and the differences between the various Linux implementation, in the context of NFSv4:  http://www.eecs.utk.edu/resources/it/kb/nfsv4-acls

Comment: @MikeRobinson, FWIW that page was moved to [this place](http://www.eecs.utk.edu/resources/it/eecs-it-knowledge-base/nfsv4-acls/). Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

**To use POSIX ACLs with NFS, you had to use NFSv3.**

NFSv4 ACLs are way different that POSIX ACLs. The first one are set using the very specific nfs4_getacl and nfs4_setacl, while the latter are configured with the standard getfacl/setfacl binaries. In short, NFSv4 ACLs have nothing to do with POSIX ACLs (NFSv4 acls are much closer to the CIFS ACLs used in Windows environment, by the way).

Comment: This is true and in addition NFSv4 ACLs are overriden by the **umask**. The umask is often 022 (remove write bit for group and other), which makes it impossible to inherit e. g. group write access. In NFSv3 it works properly.